# php preg_match extract digits from a string

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I've looked at the other questions on SO and cannot manage to adapt them for this:
How do I extract the digits between "was" and "feet" in this string?

```
Maximum was 5.29 feet at 2015-10-28 07:59 10
```

The range of those digits can range from -8.xx to 30.xx and the wording is always the same, with the initial word being Maximum or Minimum and a changing datestamp.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match the words surrounding the digits:

```
preg_match('/(?<=was )[\d.]+(?= feet)/', $string, $match);
```

Looakarounds are used to match parts of the input, but they aren't included in the match result. `$match[0]` will then contain the digits.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nA1sG9/1)

The more traditional (pre-lookaround) way is to use a capture group:

```
preg_match('/was ([\d.]+) feet/', $string, $match);
```

In this case, `$match[1]` will contain the part of the input that matched the group within the first set of parentheses.

Comment: I don't think it's the best to answer questions where you can't see any effort from OP to solve the problem himself. I think with this you support more that people going to ask questions without even trying to solve it by there own.

Comment: I generally agree, but sometimes with simple one-liners it feels cruel to drag it out.

Comment: But by doing that and see/ask OP what he has tried or say him to try something, he might be able to solve the problem by himself which has 2 good results. 1. better learn success! (Where OP even can be more happy that he solved it all by himself) 2. Maybe he learned something only from simple: "try and error" or do some research and then the next 3 questions he doesn't have to ask, because he can solve it by himself. (And if he couldn't figure it out, but he shows what he has tried, we can show him better what he has done wrong and where the mistakes are)

Comment: Anyway the answer has been posted and it's not a bad one ;D I think you could improve it with more explanations for OP what you are doing here.